# ScrollView not working or showing bar in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, android-scrollview

I have a custom fragment that contains a `ScrollView` and `TextView` that I can not for the life of me get scrolling... This was supposed to be a simple console that can scroll up to prior text and other junk but always show new text at the bottom with an option scroll lock (not implemented yet). At startup the `TextView` is empty but has a method to append and eventually fill the `TextView` from the main Activity. All of which work except scrolling. Below is the code snippet. I have tried a myriad of links from researching this and have tried nearly everything I have run across even combining attempts from other links. Still nothing. To summarize, I just want vertical scrolling with text appended to the bottom. So any advise on implementing the `ScrollView` properly? Thanks to all who help, much appreciated.

Also I'm not sure if its kosher to add all the links that iv tried and failed to get working... iv saved all tabs just encase someone found a link that I could not.

CustomFragment

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {
    ScrollView scrollView;
    TextView textView;

    public void appendText(CharSequence text) {
        textView.append(text);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(viewLayoutParams);
        textView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollLayoutParams);
        scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
        scrollView.setScrollContainer(false);
        scrollView.addView(textView);

        return scrollView;
    }
}
```

MainLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Loading of Fragment from Activity Method

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(id, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: What is the text you append to your textview and how do you want it to scroll? Does it use more space than the available space on the screen? Otherwise there’s nowhere to scroll to. Why don’t you just add the layout in XML instead of programmatically do it?

Comment: Use XML is easier and It is fast in performance there is no need to do it using code programmatically! And if you want to change contents of the Views you can get them by assigning ids

Comment: @Martin Marconicini why do i have to conform to XML? seems silly. The data in question is of a byte[] but comes in properly to the textview that is not overly long. the appending is done to end of the textview as expected. But am not able to scroll once the textview fills past the available view.

Comment: XML is the standard android markup language for defining UI widgets (among a lot of there things, namely resources). While it’s not needed, the convenience, simplicity and reusability of it, makes it a core concept in the android ecosystem. iOS does the same thing, albeit hidden by Xcode’s Interface Builder/Storyboard, there is nothing wrong in writing XML for UIs in Android. Even the visual editor in Android Studio produces XML. Plus, you have written XML for your UI already, in that “MainLayout”. Why not create a scrollable_layout.xml with that…

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to write your layouts in XML and inflate them at runtime like 99% of Android apps (including those from Google).

Creating Layouts programmatically is something you can **master** after you understand the way layouts work.

It’s easier to debug (by just looking/changing) the XML than programmatic code that you don’t know what it does (or what it’s doing). After you have your XML stubbed, you can then decide if it’s worth (most of the time it’s not) porting over to code.

This took me 3 minutes…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:parentTag="FrameLayout">

 <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." />
 </ScrollView>
</merge>
```

#### UPDATE

You need to actually *bind* your TextView before you can reference it.
I suppose at some point you [inflate your layout](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/). So your XML should have `android:id=“@+id/your_textview_id` so you’d be doing `TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);`

So now you have your reference (`tv`) and you can do `tv.setText(String)` (or append or whatever you want to call).

I believe you need to take a huge step back and read about [Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)  (directly from google).

Comment: When going this route i cant seem to update said textView... i find numerous tutorials but none seem to work. i keep getting a null pointer of my textView when trying to append text.

Comment: @Mr.Invisible If you keep getting a nullpointer post here here the stacktrace and the way you are calling `appendText(String)`

Comment: moved the textView to a static and that seemed to remove the null pointer problem from the XML approach. but i do believe i have answered my own question from above. Although im not sure why a particular section of code is causing the problem of the scrollView not scrolling..